# Span a widget over mutliple columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to span a tabWidget across the entire window in the second row instead of having it just in a single column

I have already tried resizing both the table and the column with no changes. When I resize the column in row 2, it resizes every column which I don't want.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a MCVE so that others can better understand the issue you are facing. This way it is also easier for them to formulate an answer that you can directly use to solve your problem. Have a look here for how to maximize your chances of getting an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself. I created 2 `QHBOXLayout()`. One for each row that I had. Then created a `QVBoxLayout()` and then by using `x.addLayout()` I added my Horizontal Layouts to the vertical layout. Ex:

`horLay01 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
horLay02 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
vertLay01 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
vertLay01.addLayout(horLay01)
vertLay01.addWidget(tabs, 1)
vertLay01.addLayout(horLay02)`

This was able to create my even spaced top and bottom sections while spanning my `QTabWidget()` across the entire screen. Subsequently, It resizes the widgets based on screen space which is a plus.

Comment: Hello @Italiandogs and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please edit your question to better explain what you wanted, and edit your answer alongside accordingly? The reason of this request comes from the fact that neither one of them is very clear. We appreciate that you shared your solution, but somebody might face a similar problem in the future, and making both your question and answer more clear will be very helpful for them. Also, you're using a `GHBoxLayout`, which I suppose is a typo: if that's the case, would you mind to correct that, while explaining your solution in a clearer way?